# Simplest proof that the edge of an inscribed equilateral triangle bisects the radius

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Context: I am giving a *short* talk on the Bertrand Paradox to a mixed group, many of whom have studied mathematics at a higher level some years ago.    The point of the talk is the philosophical ramifications on the Principle of Indifference, but I would very much like to be able to prove all of the results I'm relying on from first principles as my audience are a pedantic bunch.

Question:

Given a circle with an inscribed equilateral triangle and a radius that is perpendicular to one of the triangle's sides, I need to be able to show that the radius is bisected by the triangle (*not* that a perpendicular radius bisects a chord!).

This is fairly simple by route of the Central Angle Theorem and then the 30-60-90 triangle, but that gets rather involved if I have to prove even a limited version of the Central Angle Theorem.  Is there a more direct route I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The centroid trisects the median.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

(This space intentionally left blank.)